# i want to check which url is coming to my page in php

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_GET['BookNow'])){

        $url5 =  "bank.php";
        exit;
}
else{

    $url5 = "customer_display.php";
    exit;
}

//$insert is a query of phpMyadmin.

if($insert){

    "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=$url5?
         message=Your booking was completed Successfully!!!'>";
}
else{

    "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=$url5?
         message=Your booking was completed Successfully!!!'>";
}
```

but it don't work please help me

Comment: maybe add an ``echo`` before the strings?

Comment: You also exit the script before you really do anything. And look into `header("Location:...") ;` for redirecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=$url5?
         message=Your booking was completed Successfully!!!'>";
```

or even

```
header ("Location: url=$url5?
         message=Your booking was completed Successfully!!!");
```